# How to let gdb recognize eret instruction when connect to mips emulator?

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I print the packets exchanged between gdb and qemu-i386, I see that when I type `si` in gdb and current pc point to `iret` instruction, the gdb will send `vCont;s:1` to qemu-i386-server, but if the current pc point to normal instruction, the gdb will send `Z0;addr:4` and `vCont;c:1` to qemu to let qemu continue until breakpoint.

And my question is, I implemented a mips32 emulator and also the gdb server, when I type `si` in my emulator debugger and current pc point to a instruction `eret` (which is similar to iret in i386), the gdb send a `Z0;addr:4` to let me add a breakpoint after the eret instruction and then send me a `vCont;c:1` to let me continue, since the eret will set pc to epc, so the break point will never reach, and the `si` command typed in gdb end with unbounded continue. I want to let gdb just send me a `vCont;s:1`, so that the si command will only execute one instruction. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two components to getting gdb to send `vCont;s`.

First, your stub has to reply correctly to the `vCont` probe packet.  For example, gdbserver shows:

```
Sending packet: $vCont?#49...Packet received: vCont;c;C;t;s;S;r
```

Here, gdb has queried with `vCont?`, and the remote has put `s` into the reply.  So, when appropriate, gdb will send `vCont;s`.

By default, though, gdb uses its knowledge of the target's instruction set to decide how to single-step.  That is, it decodes the instruction and determines the address at which to set a "single step breakpoint".  (I don't know why it is done this way in gdb.)

Assuming your stub already replies correctly, then there are two ways to solve your problem, both involving patching gdb.

I noticed that `arm_linux_software_single_step` does this:

```
  if (target_can_do_single_step () == 1)
    return {};
```

So one idea would be to change the MIPS port to do this as well.  I don't know whether this would be accepted upstream (it may impact other MIPS stubs negatively somehow).

Or, change `mips_software_single_step` to correctly decode the `eret` instruction.  This seems like a good idea regardless.

Comment: Thanks, for myself, patch the gdb is challenging to me but I'm glad to challenge myself. But this emulator and gdb stub will be used by my junior schoolmates, maybe they cannot accept the patched gdb. So I prefer to reach this in my gdb stub. I noticed that Target Description XML maybe helpful to me, I will try this way to solve it.